# Jquery Mobile Themeroller leaves stripes in the background

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem that drives me nuts, i have used themeroller from jquery mobile and i love this tool, it has its flaws and one of them is when you use dark backgrounds it leaves a little white stripe at the top of the list you can see it right here

http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/

it is on the top , left and right of the list, its small but it is there

Is there a fix for this, so i can remove the annoying white stripe

Thanks

Dave

Comment: I would also suggest using a DOCTYPE http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp as wellas updating your jQM library to the official release http://jquerymobile.com/download/ as you're using RC1

Answer (score 0):

On this:

```
div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" ...
```

Give it:

```
 border-top:0
```

Worked at my end.

Comment: I am sorry i am kind of new whit this CSS coding stuff, where can i find "ui-btn-inner ui-li"? do i need to ad this myself... could you please explain it a little bit more. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First I would add a HTML DOCTYPE

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

I think you're missing the opening `<html>` tag

- http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/ (right click to view source)

and last I think you also need to add just the custom theme and not jQM default css

- http://jsfiddle.net/UEuKA/3/

Last I would give the jQM Theme Roller another go as it looks to be adding CSS from RC2

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/
- http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/css/style.css (jQuery Mobile v1.0rc2)

One more thing, your custom CSS could be causing the extra line as well, Didn't look at it too much though

- http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1-theme/css/custom.css

Comment: Thanks Phill i will check that all out